# Nonlinear simulation in ANSYS workbench

Tags: applied-mechanics, simulation, ansys-workbench

I'm trying to conduct a thermo-mechanical analysis in ansys workbench, I've been able to obtain some results using the transient thermal and static structural modules, however, I would like to perform a more accurate simulation.

Until this moment I just have reach a linear solution for the static structural module, as shown in the next images,

[image]

[image]

Once I get the solution from the thermal module I import it to the static structural module and solve, but there are some elements that cross each other, for example, inside the leaf of the door there are some stiffeners that cross the frontal door plate. Also the leaf interferes with the frame of the door in various locations.

How can I fix this?

I've been trying to use the static structural module with the large deflection set "on", but I'm new to this kind of analysis and I'm not been able to solve the problem.

I can send the files if it's needed.